# Target wpcf7mailsent of a specific contact 7 form

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

Im using Wordpress and Contact Form 7. I would like the user to be able to fill out a form, and after successful submit a file will download. Im using javascript to target the wpcf7mailsent event, which then directs to the file. Im forcing the pdf to download in the .htaccess file.

This all works fine, however I have multiple forms on the page, and only want this logic to apply to one specific contact 7 form. How can I get that to work. Here is the output for the HTML and JS for the form I wish this to happen on:

```
<section id="downloads"><span class="text">Download Brochure</span>
  <div class="brochure-form">
    <div class="container">
      <div><p>Please fill out the form below to download the brochure</p>
</div>
 <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f3112-o2" lang="en-GB" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/developments/sonas/#wpcf7-f3112-o2" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="3112" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_GB" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f3112-o2" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" />
</div>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your name" /></span>  </p>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Email" /></span> </p>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap tel"><input type="tel" name="tel" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-tel wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-tel" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Telephone" /></span> </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" /></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div><script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    //location = 'http://excel-homes.design-image.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/BigNeat.pdf';
}, false );
</script>
</div>
</div>
</section> 

<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    location = '<?php the_field('download_brochure'); ?>';
}, false );
</script>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you can notice the event is not related to a specific form so you cannot make it triggered for a specific form. By the way you can add some logic inside the function to test which form is being used.

To do that you may use the `event` object. As you can read [here](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) :

> User input data through the target contact form is passed to the event
>   handler as the detail.inputs property of the event object. The data
>   structure of detail.inputs is an array of objects, and each object has
>   name and value properties.

and also

> Available properties of the event object :

```
PROPERTY                      DESCRIPTION
detail.contactFormId          The ID of the contact form.
detail.pluginVersion          The version of Contact Form 7 plugin.
detail.contactFormLocale      The locale code of the contact form.
detail.unitTag                The unit-tag of the contact form.
detail.containerPostId        The ID of the post that the contact form is placed in.
```

You can add an if else statement in order to test a specific property you already specified in your form (an Id, a hidden input, etc)

---

In you case you may use the ID of your form `3112` by doing something like this :

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if(event.detail.contactFormId == '3112') {
    //put your code here 
    }
}, false );
```

If you are not sure about the ID to use, you may add a `console.log` to see the content while submitting the form and you will get the ID and the other informations:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    console.log(event.detail)
}, false );
```

Comment: Would you be able to show me what this would look like? my JS skills are limited im afraid.

Comment: Thanks, this isnt working, but ill see if can work out why

Comment: @WebblyBrown try to add the console.log as i show to see the output

Comment: Thanks for this a bit of really useful advice, you saved me time today.

Comment: Great! Intercepting CF7 callbacks is very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, instead of logging all form details, you can find the form ID in the shortcode. Most often found in domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7 and under "shortcode" column.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Add this code in child theme functions.php 
function cf7_footer_script(){ ?>
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {     
        if(event.detail.contactFormId == '906') { 
            window.open( 'YOUR URL HERE', 'download' ); 
        } 
    }, false );
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer', 'cf7_footer_script');
```

Comment: You can explain what's going on with your code so that OP understands what you really want to convey.

Answer (score -2):

Try This Code You can Differentiate form by their form id... And you can use more else if condition

```
   add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_page' );

    function redirect_page()
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        if ( '111' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
            location = 'your-url1';
        } else if ('222' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
            location = 'your-url2';
        }
    }, false );
</script>
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and the already provided one?

Comment: nothing different. but i didn't saw that code that time... m using this code so just paste it here. nothing difference.